# Arch linux: QT apps crash on launch: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, qt, sway

When I try to launch some QT apps I get this message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, xcb, minimal, offscreen, vnc.

fish: Job 1, './app' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

How can I resolve this problem so QT apps can run normally ?
Thank you for help

---

Info:

- I use wayland + sway
- I have `qt5-wayland` and `qt6-wayland` already installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Solution to this problem was to remove this line:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
```

from `/etc/environment`.

### Explanation

Thsi venv forced QT apps to run natively on wayland but some apps come with bundled QT libs and without wayland support.